# Prove that a function is solution of IVP

Tags: calculus

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^1$ and let $F$ defined by

$$F(x)=\dfrac{1}{a}\int_0^x f(t)\sin(a(x-t))dt$$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Prove that $F$ is solution of the IVP

$$y''+a^2 y'=f(x)$$
$$y(0)=y'(0)=0$$

---

I've used the fundamental Calculus theorem, but i can't get the request 'cause

$F'(x)=\dfrac{1}{a}f(x)\sin(a(x-x))(x')-\dfrac{1}{a}f(0)\sin(a(x-0))(0')=0$ ??

Anyone can help me? I've tried with integration by parts but i can't get the result too

Comment: Your last line is confusing. When you plug in $0$ for $x$, you should have no $x$s left.

Comment: Hint: Start by calculating the derivatives of F. Remember that: $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x_0}^x f(t)\, dt = f(x)$

Comment: I can't get the request because i get $F'(x)=0$ , I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$F'(x) = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^x a f(t) \cos (a (x-t)) \, dt$$
$$F''(x) = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^x -a^2 f(t) \sin (a (x-t)) \, dt+a f(x) $$

Comment: How you get those derivates?

Comment: @Jorge : Sanjab is following the Leibniz rule of differentiating an integral as seen from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: thanks! the statement had an error, the EDO must be $y''+ay=f(x)$