# Particular solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that a particular solution $y_{1}$ of the ODE
$$y''-k^{2}y=R(x)$$
$k\neq0$, is given by
$$y_{1}=\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{x}R(t)\sinh(k(x-t))dt$$

I really have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Three things: (i) you must find out what it means for $y_1$ to be a solution of $y'' - k^2y = R(x)$, (ii) you must know the fundamental theorem of calculus and (iii) $\sinh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x}).$

Comment: @snarski you can't readily apply the FTC here, the integrand depends on $x$ as well.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860604/prove-that-a-function-is-solution-of-ivp

Comment: What are the intial conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full version of the general solution of the corresponding ODE done by [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_variation_of_parameters) is $y=C_1\sinh kx+C_2\cosh kx+\sinh kx\int_0^x\dfrac{R(x)\cosh kx}{k}dx-\cosh kx\int_0^x\dfrac{R(x)\sinh kx}{k}dx$

Note that the general solution can also rewrite as

$y=C_1\sinh kx+C_2\cosh kx+\dfrac{\sinh kx}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\cosh kt~dt-\dfrac{\cosh kx}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sinh kt~dt$

$y=C_1\sinh kx+C_2\cosh kx+\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)(\sinh kx\cosh kt-\cosh kx\sinh kt)~dt$

$y=C_1\sinh kx+C_2\cosh kx+\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sinh(k(x-t))~dt$

The particular solution part is $y_1=\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sinh(k(x-t))~dt$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the Laplace transform techniques to get this solution.

**Added:** You can follow the steps:

> 1) Take the Laplace transform of the ode.
>
> 2) Rearrange and solve for $Y(s)$
>
> 3) apply the initial conditions if they have been given
>
> 4) take the inverse Laplace transform and you need to use the [convolution property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform) of the Laplace transform.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the down vote for?